# Android Notifications with flag possible?

Tags: android, android-notifications

Is it in Android possible, that I can specify some additional information on an local notification? I'm using API15.
In iOS I can do it like this:

```
+ (void)createNotificationWithDate:(NSDate *)date withText:(NSString *)text withInfo:(NSString *)additionalInfo {
    UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.fireDate = date;
    //localNotification.alertTitle = NSLocalizedString(@"Item Due", nil);
    localNotification.alertBody = text;
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;

    //Additional Info
    NSDictionary *info = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", additionalInfo] forKey:@"additionalInfoFlag"];
    localNotification.userInfo = info;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
}
```

But, how can I do this in Android?

Background is, that I want to delete in another proccess only the specific notifications with additionalInfo flag.
In iOS i've got:

```
+ (void)deleteNotificationWithAdditionalInfo:(NSString *)additionalInfo {
    UILocalNotification * notificationToCancel = nil;

    for(UILocalNotification * aNotif in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]) {
        if([[aNotif.userInfo objectForKey:@"additionalInfo"] isEqualToString:additionalInfo ]) {
            notificationToCancel = aNotif;
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notificationToCancel];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: What would you tell me? I can't find something, to add additional infos. Should I store notificationId and additional info in database to identify my notifications?

Comment: you can store additional information in a PendingIntent using a Bundle set as extra, but i don't think you can access that bundle unless the pending intent is executed. And since a notification must be cancelled by Id, then yes, you could store the additional info temporarily in sharedPreferences or a db. You would need to set another pendingIntent for when the user dismisses the notification `setDeleteIntent`, so you can delete the info from the db.

Comment: @ILovemyPoncho: thanks! Then I'm going to store the values in a flat db.